# How to Customize camera view to Custom shape like Hand Shape or Alphabets?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-custom-view

I am working in a project, where I need to show Camera preview in a custom shape.
For that, I am using Android Camera and I have successfully achieved with **Rectangle** shape using this code.

```
 ViewOutlineProvider vop2 = new ViewOutlineProvider() {
            @Override
            public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
                outline.setRect(10, 10, mProgressFrameLayout.getWidth() - 10, mProgressFrameLayout.getHeight() - 10);
            }
        };

        mCameraView.setOutlineProvider(vop2);
```

here is screenshot:

[image]

Now, I want to change rectangle to some customized shape like [Hand Shape](https://postimg.cc/image/ysuvl2ys3/) or [Alphabets](https://postimg.cc/image/suqyg9q6v/) (not Rectangle or Oval).

Here is a reference link which I follow to set shape:[Outline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline)

Comment: instead of going with complex way you can create a transparent image of your custom shape and use it as a overlay on your surface view

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig: then how can I capture an image within that overlaying shape?

Comment: ohh you also want to capture with that shape??

Comment: yes. that's why I am using current approach.

Comment: you can get bitmap from your view for image